# ASP.NET redirect pagename.aspx/something to pagename.aspx

Tags: asp.net, redirect, styles, relative-path

Ok, I didn't know how to phrase this differently. Basically, I have an issue on my website, where writing pagename.aspx/anything will open the page pagename.aspx but with no styles or images cause they have relative paths. It's not possible to rewrite them to have absolute paths. Is there any way I could make it work somehow (like for example, redirecting it)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some aspx code that contains those links to images. You can always use the tilde(`~`) to resolve the image paths: `<asp:Image ID="Img" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Name.gif" />`

Comment: Images are usually created through pure HTML (I must mention that I wasn't the one who created this website, I'm just hired to fix it), something like <img src="images/whatever.png" alt="" /> and it's like this across the site. Like I said, it's not an option to change all the URLs because the site is huge with probably several hundred pages, where all the content is mostly static.

Comment: Then make them `Image`-controls (which are rendered as `img`) and use the tilde as shown. It is resolved as the web-application's root directory.

Answer (score 1):

For converting any application root relative URL (which is the most common format) to the appropriate URL on the client in a Web Forms page, you can use this code:

```
<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/path/to/file.css") %>
```

Example:

```
<script src='<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, in cases where you're using server side controls (for example, `asp:Image` instead of plain `img` element) then you can use the application root relatively URL without needing to resolve it.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/myimage.jpg" />
```

is equivalent to

```
<img src='<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/images/myimage.jpg") %>' />
```

Comment: Thank you, but like I said, that's not really an option because there is too much content on the website. Is there no way to write a redirect rule that would redirect page.aspx/whatever to page.aspx?

Comment: @Sensei I don't do redirect rules, so I wouldn't know. I would suggest you just bite the bullet and make all the URL's application root relative. Plain relative paths are difficult to work with when you want to restructure things.